# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function NOW()

Tags: php

What I did in my code was this:

```
$date = NOW();
```

So I want `date` variable to store the current *data and timing*.

But when I run the program, I get this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function NOW()
```

So why is that?

Comment: NOW() is a mysql function, Not php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `$date = date();`, `NOW()` is for MySQL.

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php) for more information about `date()`.

Here is an example (from this documentation) :

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                   // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                           // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                         // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                             // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');       // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');     // It is the 10th day (10ème jour du mois).
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");                 // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \e\s\t\ \l\e\ \m\o\i\s'); // 17:03:18 m est le mois
$today = date("H:i:s");                           // 17:16:18
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");                     // 2001-03-10 17:16:18 (le format DATETIME de MySQL)
```

To get the current date in `datetime` format, you can do :

```
$date = new Datetime();
```

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/datetime.construct.php) for more information about `datetime`.

If you are in MySQL, you can use `NOW()` like this for example :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (current_date) VALUE (NOW())";
```

And again, here is the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) if you want to know more about `NOW()`.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$date = NOW();
```

to this:

```
$date = date();
```